# jQuery buttons - Get pressed value

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have a simple jQuery UI button set that looks like this...

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button id="button1" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" value="orange">Orange</button>
    <button id="button2" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" value="banana">Banana</button>
    <button id="button3" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" value="apple">Apple</button>
</div>
```

How can I get the value of the button that has been pressed?  Does anybody have an example they can point me in the direction of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event listener for the button element:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var value = this.value;
});
```

Check this [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/HEldursi/ob3axgLm/3/)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var buttons = $(".buttons > button");
buttons.on('click',function(){
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
    <button id="button1" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" value="orange">Orange</button>
    <button id="button2" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" value="banana">Banana</button>
    <button id="button3" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" value="apple">Apple</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.ui-button').forEach(function(item){
  item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var target = event.target.value;
    console.log(target);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Gets the value of the button last clicked.

```
document.ready(function(){
   var button = $(".ui-button.ui-widget.ui-corner-all");
   button.click(function(){
       buttonValue = $(this).val();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example

**Html**

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button id="button1" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" value="orange">Orange</button>
    <button id="button2" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" value="banana">Banana</button>
    <button id="button3" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" value="apple">Apple</button>
</div>

<span id="buttonValue"></span>
```

in jQuery you can do it like this
**JS Code**

```
  $('button').click(function(){

        var buttonValue = $(this).val();

        $('#buttonValue').text(buttonValue);
        });
```

[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pstb28rm/)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 $('button').click(function() {
    alert($(this).val())
 });
```